# What the heck kind of timestamp is this: 1267488000000

Tags: python, datetime

And how do I convert it to a datetime.datetime instance in python?

It's the output from the New York State Senate's API: http://open.nysenate.gov/legislation/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like Unix time, but with milliseconds instead of seconds?

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1267488000000 / 1000)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=61, tm_isdst=0)
```

March 2nd, 2010?

And if you want a `datetime` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1267488000000 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 1, 19, 0)
```

Note that the `datetime` is using the local timezone while the `time.struct_time` is using UTC.

Comment: But it's not a datetime instance

Comment: Updated to include datetime, including a note on timezone differences between the two approaches.

Comment: ....and in the end it's going to turn out that the New York State Senate was just thinking  *really* far ahead.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe milliseconds?

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1267488000000/1000)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=2, \
    tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=61, tm_isdst=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1267488000000/1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's in miliseconds from epoch (but rounded to tousends of seconds). Try using:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.convertunits.com/dates/from/Jan+1,+1970/to/Mar+2,+2010) is pretty informative. I think you have a time stamp in milliseconds since Thursday, January 1st, 1970.

Answer (score 2):

`1267488000000` is a epoch timestamp *with milliseconds*. It is `"Tue Mar 02 2010 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST)"` (where I live, at least)

Comment: You may want to check this. Your date looks very much like today's, where this lloks like 02 March 2010, *viz.* `>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1267488000000/1000)
2010-03-02 11:00:00`

Comment: Thanks. I used JavaScript to get it and used `Date()` instead of `new Date()`, which caused the mishap.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and the [Java Date class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) both use milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 GMT. Both languages are commonly used in web services.

Comment: Thank you--and this web service was indeed written in java.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a timestamp (the number of milliseconds since the epoch). You want `date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Unix timestamp. See [here](http://seehuhn.de/pages/pdate) for some time conversions in python.